# Prove that for $C_i\in \mathscr{C}$ and $C=\bigcup C_i $ $ C\in \mathscr{C}. \ $ $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain of S

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

$D\neq (1)$ is an ideal in ring $A\neq0$. Now $A$ has a maximal ideal $I$ such that $D\subseteq I. \ $

Now consider the following set $$S=\{I_i \ |\ I_i\leq A, D\subseteq I_i\}$$ $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain of $S. \ $ Prove that for $C_i\in \mathscr{C}$ and   $C=\bigcup C_i $

$$ C\in \mathscr{C}$$ This is mentioned in my book. Can someone help me how can I start this proof. Thanks

Comment: First prove that $C$ is an ideal.

Comment: @user26857 Is it enough to show that $C$ is an ideal?

Comment: Anyway, I think you have to show $C\in S$.

Comment: In principle yes, its enough.

Comment: @user26857 I think It is also important to show that $D\subseteq C. \ $Isn't it?

Comment: How is a 'chain' defined? In case, we might rather take $\mathscr C$ as a *maximal* chain..

Comment: @Hitman $D\subseteq C$ is obvious. Isn't it?